# Regex with specific characters at specific places

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex which will match a word, which can have 2 or 3 characters:

First one must be a or b, second must be c or empty, and third one must be d or e. 
How to "tell" regex that there will be exactly 3 chars with different requirements for each?

I tried something like this:

```
"[ab],[c]*,[de]"
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Search for the java of `Pattern`.

Comment: Of course, sorry. I added my attempt to solve this.

Comment: Please add the example strings and tell us how it works or fails. Are you matching the whole string? Maybe you need anchors?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have solved it myself. I just had to erase commas.

Comment: You also need to change `*` after `[c]` to a `?`, otherwise it will match a string like `accccccd`. And ideally you should add `^` and `$` anchors to the start and finish of the regex so that it has to match the *entire* string. Otherwise it might match `1ace2`.